# installing tensorflow-r1.14 C API

Tags: c, api, tensorflow, machine-learning

currently I am taking my first steps in the field of machine learning, and I have been requested by the start-up I will be working for to download a specific version (which is quite outdated). I have downloaded the C extension that includes two or three headers for Visual Studio, however, I am unable to locate the actual requirements needed to download and run TensorFlow itself. Can someone kindly provide me with a link or any helpful information?

Despite searching for information on the internet, asking ChatGPT, and consulting with several colleagues, the answers I received were not satisfactory.

Comment: This might be better fitting over at [superuser](https://superuser.com).  This site is more for code help.